# Правки по странице «Манифест Stack Overflow на русском» в справке

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

В [«Манифесте Stack Overflow на русском»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto) пару правок хорошо бы внести:

1. > Решение: неограниченно, вовремя, развернуто

   Разв**ё**рнуто.

   > Создать мир, в котором на каждый запрос к поисковику, в выдаче есть ссылка на развернутый ответ на русском языке.

   Разв**ё**рнутый.
2. > Участники управляют содержимым сайта и увлекают за собо коллег своим примером.

   Собо**й**.
3. > Участники учат коллег и учимся у них бесплатно. Результат взаимодействия — база знаний по программированию на русском языке — находится в свободном доступе сообщества.

   **учимся** -> **учатся**.
4. > Мысли позади миссии: Международные Stack Overflow: неограниченно, вовремя, развернуто на родном языке

   Разв**ё**рнуто.

Comment: «Информации, а не знаний» — дайте, пожалуйста, точные определения этих терминов. А то иначе мы скатимся в терминологический спор.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ага, чуть позже добавлю.

Comment: В общем, со всеми правками кроме «знаний» я согласен, а про знания ваще непонятно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin как-то неоднозначно всё с этим. Убрал из вопроса от греха по дальше, а то, мне кажется, к консенсусу не придём в этом вопросе )